# Bower failing on Azure deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, bower

I'm using Azure to deploy a Node.js web application.  I've linked Github as my deployment repo, and set up the deploy.sh as mentioned in Jay Harris's webpage: http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx

My app depends on bower, but when it tries to deploy, I get a bower failed error.  Here is the output from the Azure log:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\videogelpub\AppData\npm\bower -> C:\DWASFiles\Sites\videogelpub\AppData\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.3.1 C:\DWASFiles\Sites\videogelpub\AppData\npm\node_modules\bower
├── is-root@0.1.0
├── junk@0.2.2
error: could not lock config file d:/home/.gitconfig: Permission denied
├── stringify-object@0.2.0
├── abbrev@1.0.4
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.5
├── osenv@0.0.3
├── archy@0.0.2
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.6
├── open@0.0.4
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.1
├── lru-cache@2.5.0
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── nopt@2.1.2
├── retry@0.6.0
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── tmp@0.0.23
├── chalk@0.4.0 (has-color@0.1.4, ansi-styles@1.0.0, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── q@1.0.1
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── shell-quote@1.4.1 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-map@0.0.0, array-reduce@0.0.0, jsonify@0.0.0)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (deep-extend@0.2.8, intersect@0.0.3)
├── semver@2.2.1
├── p-throttler@0.0.1 (q@0.9.7)
├── fstream@0.1.25 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── fstream-ignore@0.0.7 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── tar@0.1.19 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7)
├── glob@3.2.9 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.14)
├── decompress-zip@0.0.5 (nopt@2.2.0, mkpath@0.1.0, touch@0.0.2, readable-stream@1.1.12, binary@0.3.0)
├── request@2.33.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime@1.2.11, form-data@0.1.2, tough-cookie@0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.0.0)
├── cardinal@0.4.4 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.4)
├── inquirer@0.4.1 (readline2@0.1.0, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@2.3.4, async@0.2.10, lodash@2.4.1, cli-color@0.2.3)
├── update-notifier@0.1.8 (semver@2.1.0, request@2.27.0, configstore@0.2.3)
├── handlebars@1.3.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── bower-config@0.5.0 (optimist@0.6.1, mout@0.6.0)
├── mout@0.9.0
├── insight@0.3.1 (object-assign@0.1.2, async@0.2.10, lodash.debounce@2.4.1, request@2.27.0, configstore@0.2.3)
└── bower-registry-client@0.1.6 (request-replay@0.2.0, lru-cache@2.3.1, async@0.2.10, request@2.27.0, bower-config@0.4.5)
bower angular#1.2.11        not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.11
bower angular#1.2.11           resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.11
bower json3#~3.2.6          not-cached git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.6
bower json3#~3.2.6             resolve git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.6
bower es5-shim#~2.1.0       not-cached git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~2.1.0
bower es5-shim#~2.1.0          resolve git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~2.1.0
bower jquery#~1.11.0        not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.11.0
bower jquery#~1.11.0           resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.11.0
bower angular-cookies#1.2.11       not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.11
bower angular-cookies#1.2.11          resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.11
bower angular-route#1.2.11         not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.11
bower angular-route#1.2.11            resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.11
bower querystring#~3.24.10         not-cached git://github.com/anodynos/node2web_querystring.git#~3.24.10
bower querystring#~3.24.10            resolve git://github.com/anodynos/node2web_querystring.git#~3.24.10
bower bootstrap#~3.0.3                 cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.3
bower bootstrap#~3.0.3               validate 3.0.3 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.3
bower angular-resource#1.2.11          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.11
bower angular-resource#1.2.11        validate 1.2.11 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.11
bower angular-sanitize#1.2.11          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.11
bower angular-sanitize#1.2.11        validate 1.2.11 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.2.11
bower underscore#~1.6.0                cached git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#1.6.0
bower underscore#~1.6.0              validate 1.6.0 against git://github.com/jashkenas/underscore.git#~1.6.0
bower angular-mocks#1.2.11             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.11
bower angular-mocks#1.2.11           validate 1.2.11 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.11
bower angular-scenario#1.2.11          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.11
bower angular-scenario#1.2.11        validate 1.2.11 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.11
bower json3#~3.2.6                   download https://github.com/bestiejs/json3/archive/v3.2.6.tar.gz
bower angular-cookies#1.2.11         download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies/archive/v1.2.11.tar.gz
bower angular-route#1.2.11           download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route/archive/v1.2.11.tar.gz
bower angular#1.2.11                 download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.11.tar.gz
bower angular-cookies#1.2.11          extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-cookies#1.2.11         resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.2.11
bower angular-route#1.2.11            extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-route#1.2.11           resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.11
bower angular#1.2.11                  extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#1.2.11                 resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.11
bower json3#~3.2.6                   progress received 3.0MB of 4.9MB downloaded, 60%
bower json3#~3.2.6                   progress received 4.0MB of 4.9MB downloaded, 82%
bower json3#~3.2.6                    extract archive.tar.gz
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
bower failed
```

Can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your question after dealing with this myself and not finding any resources on line. I used a really similar deployment file and script that you listed in the link, but got a similar error to what you listed.

It's confusing because the Azure log shows that everything is being installed from the bower.json file and it only errors at the end.

First of all, make sure you have bower in npm (the node_modules folder). It looks like you do.

Secondly, run `bower install` in your command line. In my case, it installed everything, but at the end, gave this message:
[image: bower error]

I selected option 3 because it is the newest version of Angular and, I assume, backwards compatible with the rest. The bang (!) adds it to the bower.json folder. I committed, pushed to my repo, and redeployed on Azure...this time, it deployed without error!